# Bootstrap 3 panel group collapse outside of group

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think I am doing this a slightly silly way, and so am happy to take suggestions for a new approach.

I am creating a accordion style dropdown nav for mobile but I want the target divs to be outside of the panel group. My code is of the form:

```
<div class='panel-group' id='accordian'>

  <div class='mystyles'>
    <ul>
     <li>
       <div class='nav-item'>
         <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordian' href='#target-one-id'>Item 1</a>
       </div>
     </li>
      .... more list items here...
    </ul
  </div>
  <!-- the collapsed divs start here -->
  <div id='target-one-id' class='clearfix collapse panel-collapse'>
    ...content
  </div>
  ... more target divs here
</div>  <!-- end panel group -->
```

I have chosen to do this as I need to style the links differently to the collapsed divs and I want them to appear lower down the page. It does generally work, however, to make a target div collapse you have to click on it's parent link. I want the child to collapse whenever any of the list links are clicked. Or in other words I want only one target div visible at any one time.

I may just not understand bootstrap but how would I go about doing this?

EDIT: A bad solution

So I have a slightly rough solution where I add js code of the form:

```
$("#target-one").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
                $("#target-two").collapse('hide');
                $("#target-three").collapse('hide');
             });
```

This works but the transition animation is jerky and the targets being closed appear to reopen and close as they are hidden. What is a better solution?

```js
$("#target-one").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
                $("#target-two").collapse('hide');
                $("#target-three").collapse('hide');
             });
$("#target-two").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
                $("#target-one").collapse('hide');
                $("#target-three").collapse('hide');
             });
$("#target-three").on("show.bs.collapse", function(){
                $("#target-two").collapse('hide');
                $("#target-one").collapse('hide');
             });
```

```css
.mystyles ul {
  list-style-type:none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.mystyles ul li {
 display:inline-block;
}
.mycontent {
  background-color:orange;
}
.one {
 height:300px;
 background-color:pink;
}
.two {
 width:200px;
 height:500px;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='panel-group' id='accordian'>
    <div class='mystyles'>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class='nav-item'>
            <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordian' href='#target-one'>Item 1</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class='nav-item'>
            <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordian' href='#target-two'>Item 2</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class='nav-item'>
            <a data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordian' href='#target-three'>Item 3</a>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul </div>
      <!-- the collapsed divs start here -->
      <div id='target-one' class='clearfix collapse panel-collapse'>
        <div class='mycontent one'>
          content...
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id='target-two' class='clearfix collapse panel-collapse'>
        <div class='mycontent two'>
          content...
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id='target-three' class='clearfix collapse panel-collapse'>
        <div class='mycontent three'>
          content...
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end panel group -->
</body>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Ok so the snippet seems to work properly... I am now a little confused. My actual code is almost identical except for some dynamic content which is inserted into the target divs.

Could resizing of the hidden diff cause problems? I do not know how to simulate that in the snippet.

Comment: Please provide a working example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)/[snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/))